# send multiple order confirmation emails to user

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have opencart 2.3 installed on my site and im trying to add a new email template.

So once the user has made a purchase i want to send an extra email along with the order confirmation email which contains instructions and a code.

So far i have edited the model/checkout/order.php

after

```
$mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
$mail->setText($text);
$mail->send();
```

i added the below code

```
$mailx = new Mail();
$mailx->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mailx->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mailx->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mailx->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mailx->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mailx->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mailx->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

$mailx->setTo("test@email.com"); // test email address
$mailx->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mailx->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mailx->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject."- Download Links", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mailx->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/instructions', $data));
$mailx->setText("email content");
$mailx->send();
```

So once the order is confirmed i get only the confirmation email, not the second instruction email.

When i replace it with a simple php mail() function to test its working, but not with the above code.

Can someone let me know what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error with this method?

Comment: nope... No errors and logs dont have any errors related to it

Comment: you don't need to instantiate `Mail()` again.  Just use `setSubject()`, `setHtml()`, and `setText()` to update content and send as usual.  If that's not working you probably have an ocmod caching the file and you'll need to update ocmod cache.